# Adobe help center magento 2.4.3

Tags: magento2.4.3, adobe-commerce

We suddenly got a blue dot with a hat on out magento admin. It's called Adobe help center. It makes our Admin super slow. Anyone know how to turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

> **You can run the below command to disable it.**

```
php bin/magento config:set admin/usage/enabled 0
```

> **If you want to disabled using Admin Go to Stores -> Configuration** -> **Admin -> Admin Usage -> Enable Admin Usage Tracking**

[image]

> You can also disable **Magento_AdminAnalytics** module using below command.

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_AdminAnalytics
```

Comment: Thank you, will try this. But do you know how it could suddenly appear like that? this has never been active on out admin before

Comment: Please check this link : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37618

Comment: Wow.. I love Adobe, how it just does one little thing and your entire Store admin panel is broken